# python opencv multithreading - multiple usb cameras

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, ubuntu, usb

I'm trying to store images from 4 different usb cameras (640x480). I'm using the threading module from python to store images simultaneously from multiple cameras. My code seems to work for 3 cameras, but fails to return images for camera 3. I'm trying to capture images every one second for 6 seconds from each camera.
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
python3

```
import cv2
import time
import datetime
import os
import threading

NUMBER_OF_CAMERAS = 2


class CameraCapture:
   def __init__(self, camera_path):
       # extract folder path here and add /cam1 /cam2
       self.camera_type = camera_path

       if camera_path == "/dev/video0":
           self.camera_type = "FRONT"
       elif camera_path == "/dev/video2":
           self.camera_type = "REAR"
       elif camera_path == "/dev/video4":
           self.camera_type = "LEFT"
       elif camera_path == "/dev/video6":
           self.camera_type = "RIGHT"

       self.is_capture_complete = False
       self.stop_capture = False
       self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_path)

       print("CAMERA OBJECT FOR:{} INITIALIZED".format(camera_path))

   def __del__(self):
       self.camera.release()

   def display_camera_data(self):
       while True:
           ret, frame = self.camera.read()
           cv2.imshow('frame1', frame)
           cv2.moveWindow('frame', 0, 0)

   def start_capture(self, FrameRate: float, CapturePeriod: int):
       self.is_capture_complete = False
       self.stop_capture = False
       start_time = time.time()
       while not self.stop_capture:
           frame_interval = time.time()
           ret, frame = self.camera.read()
           camera_one_img_name = self.camera_type + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ".png"
           print("Camera ID:{} ,Image Returned:{}".format(self.camera_type, ret))
           if ret:
               print("Image Returned:{}".format(ret))
               cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("IMGS", camera_one_img_name), frame)
               print("{} written!".format(camera_one_img_name))
           while True:
               if (time.time() - frame_interval) > FrameRate:
                   print("Cheking Frame Rate:{}".format(round(time.time() - frame_interval, 2)))
                   break
           time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time
           if time_elapsed > CapturePeriod:
               self.is_capture_complete = True
               break

   def IsCaptureComplete(self) -> bool:
       return self.is_capture_complete

   def StopCapture(self) -> bool:
       self.stop_capture = True
       print("STOPING IMAGE CAPTURE")

   def testing_while(self):
       while True:
           print("Testing thread"+self.camera_type)
           time.sleep(0.1)

   def startwhile(self):
       """Function that initailaizes a thread to start scanner logic"""
       self.whiletest = threading.Thread(target=self.testing_while, name='testing while')
       self.whiletest.deamon = False
       self.whiletest.start()

   def startImageLog(self, frame_rate, capture_period):
       """Function that initailaizes a thread to start scanner logic"""
       self.image_logger = threading.Thread(target=self.start_capture, args=(frame_rate, capture_period,),
                                            name='data log')
       self.image_logger.deamon = False
       self.image_logger.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   CAM1 = CameraCapture('/dev/video0')    # FRONT
   CAM2 = CameraCapture('/dev/video2')     # REAR
   CAM3 = CameraCapture('/dev/video4')     # LEFT
   CAM4 = CameraCapture('/dev/video6')     # RIGHT

   CAM1.startImageLog(1, 6)
   CAM2.startImageLog(1, 6)
   CAM3.startImageLog(1, 6)
   CAM4.startImageLog(1, 6)

   print("Still runs")
```

Output for the same:

```
 [ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1758) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not read from resource.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
CAMERA OBJECT FOR:/dev/video0 INITIALIZED
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1758) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not read from resource.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
CAMERA OBJECT FOR:/dev/video2 INITIALIZED
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1758) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not read from resource.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
CAMERA OBJECT FOR:/dev/video4 INITIALIZED
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1758) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not read from resource.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (888) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
CAMERA OBJECT FOR:/dev/video6 INITIALIZED
Still runs
Camera ID:LEFT ,Image Returned:False
Camera ID:RIGHT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
RIGHT2020-12-28 12:27:26.976293.png written!
Camera ID:REAR ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
REAR2020-12-28 12:27:27.173821.png written!
Camera ID:FRONT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Camera ID:LEFT ,Image Returned:False
Camera ID:REAR ,Image Returned:True
Camera ID:RIGHT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
FRONT2020-12-28 12:27:27.494774.png written!
REAR2020-12-28 12:27:27.506737.png written!
RIGHT2020-12-28 12:27:27.506838.png written!
Cheking Frame Rate:1.08
Camera ID:FRONT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
FRONT2020-12-28 12:27:27.622620.png written!
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Cheking Frame Rate:1.01
Cheking Frame Rate:1.01
Camera ID:REAR ,Image Returned:True
Camera ID:RIGHT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
Camera ID:LEFT ,Image Returned:False
Image Returned:True
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
RIGHT2020-12-28 12:27:28.506592.png written!
Camera ID:FRONT ,Image Returned:True
REAR2020-12-28 12:27:28.506488.png written!
Image Returned:True
FRONT2020-12-28 12:27:28.703343.png written!
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Cheking Frame Rate:1.01
Camera ID:LEFT ,Image Returned:False
Camera ID:REAR ,Image Returned:True
Camera ID:RIGHT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
RIGHT2020-12-28 12:27:29.532898.png written!
REAR2020-12-28 12:27:29.517167.png written!
Camera ID:FRONT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
FRONT2020-12-28 12:27:29.756650.png written!
Cheking Frame Rate:1.01
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Camera ID:REAR ,Image Returned:True
Camera ID:LEFT ,Image Returned:False
Image Returned:True
Camera ID:RIGHT ,Image Returned:True
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Image Returned:True
REAR2020-12-28 12:27:30.527007.png written!
Camera ID:FRONT ,Image Returned:True
RIGHT2020-12-28 12:27:30.552778.png written!
Image Returned:True
FRONT2020-12-28 12:27:30.670008.png written!
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Cheking Frame Rate:1.01
Camera ID:LEFT ,Image Returned:False
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
Camera ID:REAR ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
Camera ID:RIGHT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
RIGHT2020-12-28 12:27:31.566817.png written!
REAR2020-12-28 12:27:31.561589.png written!
Camera ID:FRONT ,Image Returned:True
Image Returned:True
FRONT2020-12-28 12:27:31.735045.png written!
Cheking Frame Rate:1.0
```

Camera 3 - LEFT - seems to be working fine, when i launch it individually.
Where im i going wrong?

Comment: Are all fourth cameras are the same device models?

Comment: Yes. All cameras are of the same make. Also the serial attributed gets assigned according the port it connects to and is not unique.